# Excel VBA: efficient way to load data in a workbook with a lot of formulas

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel VBA code that reads the master data, load the data of each case/loop into a workbook, and then tons of calculations take place via numerous formulas (with no VBA codes). The desired result is the outputs of the calculations. The code loops through all the cases in the master data.

So here is the problem. I used multiple 'copy and paste' actions in each loop to load the data into the workbook, but the run time is way longer than I expected, causing Excel to be 'Not Responding'. Note that I already turned off automatic calculations in Excel and added the workbook Calculate trigger in the VBA code, so as to avoid updating the workbook entirely every time there is a paste action.

Could someone advise if directly setting the cells in the wb = the cells in the master data would speed up or slow down the code? Or could someone suggest a more efficient way of loading data?

I appreciate your effort before you send in your responses.

Comment: assigning the values directly would be quicker then using the clipboard.

Comment: Working in memory (e.g arrays) and bulk loading data is always faster than looping.

Comment: Also don't use `.Select` in your code, perhaps turn off screen updating or calcualtion once they've been run.

Comment: You should turn off Application.Events as well, in case you have some of them hooked to VBA code. Then, you should assign values directly from the source worksheet to the destination one, using as large rectangular ranges as possible, i.e. `DestinationWorksheet.Range("SomeNamedRange").Value = SourceWorksheet.Range("SourceRangeOfSameSize").Value`

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, not using `.Select` improves the speed of your macro. Also, copy paste actions are indeed more slow whith VBA and you should do assignations `FromWorksheet.Range("CopyRange").Value = ToWorksheet.Range("PasteRange").Value`. Also, it always helps to add these lines in the beginning:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

and reactivating them at the end:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

There are many information on this, like this [link](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/SpeedingUpVBACode.htm)